# How to disable Chrome save your password? (Selenium Java)

Tags: selenium, java, chromedriver

What is the method to disable this pop-up:

> Do you want Google Chrome to save your password for this site?

[image]

How to do this with Selenium Webdriver (Java)?

Comment: Recently i have updated my chrome driver to 2.28 version

Comment: Is the browser one you have control over and only used by the suite?

Answer (score 13):

[See the answer to "ChromeDriver user preferences ignored"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793277/chromedriver-user-preferences-ignored)

```
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```

Comment: Only credentials_enable_service is needed in my setup, but good answer.

Comment: For Selenium Java, this should NOT be the accepted answer as there is no such method named "AddUserProfilePreference" on the ChromeOptions class.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer because Chromedriver is language agnostic. I am a PHP developer using Codeception, poor, poor me.

Answer (score 8):

In Java:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: This works as of Selenium 3.3.1 using selenium-chrome-driver 3.3.1 under Java 8. Thanks @Flavio Barisi all of the other comments seemed to be targeting other languages other than Java. This probably should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

What Flavio Barisi said, with the addition of the capabilities you pass to your driver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver cannot interact with browser and/or OS specific dialogs. You can make the following changes manually in the browser to disable the dialogue.

1. Choose the Settings menu option
2. Click the Show advanced settings… (at the bottom of the page)
3. In the “Passwords and forms” section, disable the Manage passwords
   tickbox.

Comment: manually i could do but i dont know how to do that in selenium web driver.

Comment: I am afraid that that isnt possible. WebDriver cannot interact with browser and/or OS specific dialogs.

Comment: some times it is coming and some times it is not coming. i dont know how to control it

Comment: @ECiurleo For some reason i have manually disabled the offer to save password option in Manage PAssword tickbox. but still when chrome opens it shows the popup.

Comment: This is only half-way true. It cannot interact with the elements, but as you can see from the other answers, it can configure Chrome before startup not to show them :-)

Comment: That's a distinction between webdriver and java.  Webdriver itself can't interact

Answer (score 1):

This works good with latest ChromeDriver:

```
_chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
```

Comment: interesting option.  Can you provide a link to the documentation as part of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  preferences = {credentials_enable_service: false,
                 password_manager_enabled: false}
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
  capabilities['chromeOptions'] = {'prefs' => preferences}
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
                                 desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript;

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

...

const driver = new webdriver
  .Builder()
  .usingServer(url)
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().setUserPreferences({
    "credentials_enable_service": false,
    "profile.password_manager_enabled": false
  }))
  .build();
```